# Blazor, virtualized checkbox list

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to implement new "**Virtualize**" feature, by creating an scrollable list of checkboxes, where user can search and select multiple items.

Here is my razor code:

```
@if (this.AllowSearch)
{
    <InputTextLined Label="@string.Empty" @bind-Value="@SearchString"/>
}

<Virtualize Items="@displayedItems" Context="item" >
    <ItemContent>
        <label><input type="checkbox" @bind-value="item.Selected" />@item.DisplayName</label>
    </ItemContent>
</Virtualize>

</ul>
```

Heres my component code:

```
    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowSearch { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public string DisplayPropertyName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ICollection<T> SourceList { get; set; } = null;

    [Parameter]
    public Func<T, string, bool> SearchFunc { get; set; }

    public string SearchString 
    { 
        get => _searchString;
        set 
        {
            if (value == _searchString)
                return;

            _searchString = value;
            Search();
        }
    }
    private string _searchString = string.Empty;

    protected ICollection<SelectableListItemModel<T>> items;
    protected ICollection<SelectableListItemModel<T>> displayedItems;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (SourceList != null)
        {
            items = SourceList.Select(i => new SelectableListItemModel<T>(i, DisplayPropertyName)).ToList();
            displayedItems = items.ToList();
        }
    }

    protected void Search()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString) == false)
            displayedItems = items.Where(p => SearchFunc(p.Data, SearchString)).ToList();
        else
            displayedItems = items.ToList();
    }
```

The component renders all the items from sourceList by wraping them in SelectableListItemModel.

```
public class SelectableListItemModel<T> 
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public SelectableListItemModel(T data, string displayedPropertyName)
    {
        this.selected = false;
        this.Data = data;

        if (displayedPropertyName != string.Empty)
            this.DisplayName = typeof(T).GetProperty(displayedPropertyName).GetValue(data).ToString();
        else
            this.DisplayName = data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now the main issue is with search implementation. But the problem is really hard to explain. Heres picture:

[image]

When item is selected and then performed a search, checkboxes are not rerendered, only labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `InputCheckbox` rather than html `input` element. The InputCheckBox implemented `ValueChanged` to notify the parents. And also use `@item.Selected`(with `@` at the beginning) instead of `item.Selected` because `item.selected` is string! :

```
<EditForm>
<Virtualize Items="@displayedItems" Context="item" >
    <ItemContent>
        <label><InputCheckbox @bind-value="@item.Selected"></InputCheckbox>@item.DisplayName</label>
    </ItemContent>
</Virtualize>
</EditForm>
```

And

```
   protected aync Task Search()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString) == false)
            {
                displayedItems = items.Where(p => await SearchFunc(p.Data,SearchString)).ToList();
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            else
                displayedItems = items.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: That didnt help. Every time I perform a search with or without StateHasChanged is the same. State of the list changes and only proper items are displayed, what is wrong is the checked status of the checkbox.

Comment: InputCheckbox requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputCheckbox inside an EditForm.

Comment: YeS! Using InputCheckbox solved the problem. I have no ida why tho...

Comment: @DavidWaldo very good ! if you look at Microsoft's InputBase source code you will see the events that been used to notify UI changes